# How to install particular version of libc6-dev

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install particular version of `libc6-dev` on my `Ubuntu-20.04 LTS` docker container to compile our old project source code. But with the below steps it is not working.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-security-proposed/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6-dev=2.23-0ubuntu11.2
```

Getting below error during installation:

```
apt-get install libc6-dev=2.23-0ubuntu11.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.23-0ubuntu11.2' for 'libc6-dev' was not found
```

Could someone help me install the above version? Thanks

Comment: Don't do it!! `libc6` is an important component of Ubuntu, and a lot of software depend on the specific version that is installed by default. This may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please edit the question and ask why you need the specific version of libc6. If you really need the latest version of some package then use snap/flatpak, or switch to a rolling release distro.

Comment: Look up that PPA at launchpad.net. Older packages are usually archived there. Back up your data before you begin, of course, in case the old package breaks your system.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi, `libc6-dev=2.23-0ubuntu11.2` is required to build our project code. So it not recommended and not possible on `Ubuntu-20.04LTS`?

Comment: No, use a Docker image of whichever version of Ubuntu that came from instead.

Comment: Currently I'm using docker image - Ubuntu-20.04, To use this particular version of `libc6-dev=2.23-0ubuntu11.2` i need to use `Ubuntu-16.04LTS` now?

Comment: You need to use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which has `2.23-0ubuntu11.3` (check [repology](https://repology.org/project/glibc/versions) or `rmadison libc6-dev` output). But this solution requires ESM system which is off-topic here. Good moment here - you are playing with Docker, so such experiments are safe.